# How to use xcodebuild in Coverity?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcodebuild, coverity

In order to analyse my iOS application in Coverity, I am trying to use `cov-build` in conjunction with `xcodebuild`.

The command I run is:

`cov-build --no-sip-check --dir intermediate xcodebuild -scheme {scheme}`

The build is successful, yet emits no files:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration
or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.
Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.
 For more details, please look at: 
    /Users/bartk/Desktop/objctest/intermediate/build-log.txt
NL1MCL-506614:objctest bartk$ cov-analyze --dir intermediate 
Coverity Static Analysis version 8.7.0 on Darwin 16.4.0 x86_64
```

The same happens when I compile a simple HelloWorld program using the following command, `cov-build --no-sip-check --dir itermediate clang -framework Foundation program.m`, where 'no files are emitted'.

When I look into the `objctest.build` folder, all object files are there.

Of course, when I run `cov-analyze` after, it presents the following error:

```
Using 8 workers as limited by CPU(s)
Looking for translation units
Error: intermediate directory contains no translation units.
```

How can I make Coverity `cov-build` work with a Xcode project?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured your compiler with `cov-configure`? Most likely you want something of this variety: `cov-configure --compiler gcc --comptype clangcc --template`

Since Apple calls their Clang `gcc`, it's usually necessary to explicity specify the comptype here, since `gcc` on MacOSX is most definitely not GCC.

Comment: I have used `cov-configure --clang`, which resulted in the output I posted. I also tried your `cov-configure --compiler gcc --comptype clangcc --template` but it gives me the same error.

Comment: I see by your edit that your binary is named `clang`, so `cov-configure --clang` should have worked. Have you looked in the build log to see if any issues are reported and what those are?